# Serviceworker Bug event.respondWith

Tags: javascript, service-worker, progressive-web-apps

My serviceworker has the logic that when a fetch event happens,first it fetches an endpoint which contains some boolean value (not the event.request.url) and check the value , based on the value i am calling **event.respondWith()** for the current fetch event, where i am serving the response from cache.But i am getting the following error ,

> Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: Failed to execute 'respondWith' on
>   'FetchEvent': The fetch event has already been responded to

I checked [here](https://github.com/bloomberg/chromium.bb/blob/master/src/third_party/WebKit/Source/modules/serviceworkers/RespondWithObserver.cpp) that this error is throws when ***m_state*** is not equal to **Initial**

```
if (m_state != Initial) {
    exceptionState.throwDOMException(InvalidStateError, "The fetch event has already been responded to.");
    return;
}
```

I am doubting that since i am having an additional fetch event somehow it is consuming the previous fetch event,it is changing the m_state variable,though i am not fetching the event url.I am not sure what could be the reason and what is the solution for it.But why is it saying

I am pasting my code snippet below.

```
function fetchEvt(event) {        
    check().then(function (status) {
        if (status === 0) {
            handleRequest(event);
        }
    });
}

function checkHash() {
    return new Promise(function (resolve) {
        fetch(endpoint, { credentials: 'include' }).then(function (response) {
            return response.text();
        }).then(function (text) {
            resolve(text);
        });
    }
}

function handleRequest(event) {
    event.respondWith(caches.match(event.request.url).then(function (Response) {
        if (Response) {
            return Response;
        }
        return fetch(event.reuqest);
    }));
}
```

The **event.respondWith** part is throwing the error.Please suggest how to solve this problem.

edit :

```
function handleRequest(event) {
    event.respondWith(checkHash().then(function (status) {
        if (status === true) {
            caches.match(event.request.url).then(function (Response) {
                if (Response) {
                    return Response;
                }
                return fetch(event.reuqest);
            });
        } else if (status === false) return fetch(event.reuqest);
}));
```

Answer (score 7):

You need to call `event.respondWith` synchronously when handling `fetch` event. If you don't, browser assumes it should proceed with handling the request. That's why when you get around to calling `respondWith` in your code the request is already handled and you see the *fetch event has already been responded to* exception.

In other words: try calling your `checkHash` inside of `handleRequest` and not the other way around.

Comment: inside handle request or event.respondWith

Comment: i tried to move it inside event.respondWith , now it is saying **resulted in a network error response: an object that was not a Response was passed to respondWith()**

Comment: You've misspelled *request* as *reuqest* in two places.

Comment: yeah but even after fixing that same error occurs , if there is another fetch inside event.respondWith it throws this error.

Answer (score 0):

Re "since i am having an additional fetch event somehow it is consuming the previous fetch event" this shouldn't be a problem; you can `fetch()` from within the `fetch` event handler and things will work out fine:

```
self.addEventListener("fetch", e => {
  e.respondWith(
    fetch("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans")
    .then(_ => fetch(e.request))
  );
});
```

I don't quite understand what you're trying to achieve with your code but fetching multiple times, with the first influencing the behavior of the second, works fine.

Comment: This will lead to multiple fetch and looks like could sluggish things around.

Comment: @GalBracha I don't completely understand the original question, but it appears multiple fetch is desired? Did you not get that impression?