# use async function in respondWith

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, service-worker

I have a async function for caching in 'fetch' eventListener then i call this function in 'respondWith()', with 'await' but it doesn't work .

PS: when i call it without await its works

```
self.addEventListener('fetch', async e => {
      const req = e.request;
      e.respondWith(await networkAndCache(req));
      console.log('fetch');
});
```

,

```
async function networkAndCache(req) {
  const cache = await caches.open(cacheName);
  try {
    const fresh = await fetch(req);
    console.log('fresh');
    await cache.put(req, fresh.clone());
    console.log('put');
    return fresh;
  } catch (e) {
    const cached = await cache.match(req);
    console.log('cached');
    return cached || caches.match(offlineUrl);;
  }
}
```

Comment: How exactly "does it not work"?

Comment: i want freeze in this line 'e.respondWith(await networkAndCache(req));' until answer return then proceed

Answer (score 4):

You have to call `respondWith` **synchronously**. If you use `await`, `respondWith` will be called some time in the future, outside of the event handling process. Since it's outside, the browser thinks handling the event was not successful.

In order to be able to use the result of an asynchronous function,`respondWith` also accepts a promise, which is what you get if you *don't use* `await`.

So yes, not using `await` is the way to go here.

Sources:

- https://github.com/w3c/ServiceWorker/issues/836
- [Serviceworker Bug event.respondWith](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36062941/serviceworker-bug-event-respondwith)

Answer (score 2):

In your specific. case, just drop the `async`/`await` on listener. All DOM events are synchronous.

---

To use respondWith, you must pass a Promise. You can do `new Promise()` `Promise.resolve()`, or `(async () => {})()`, `async function{}()` or `myAsyncFunction()`.

```js
/**
 * @param {FetchEvent} event
 * @return {void}
 */
function onFetch(event) {
  if (event.preloadResponse) {
    // Respond with an pre-created Response object
    event.respondWith(event.preloadResponse);
    return;
  }
  // Respond with a Promise that resolves with a Response object
  // Execute an async function which returns a Promise<Response>
  event.respondWith((async () => {
    const cacheResponse = await self.caches.match(event.request, { ignoreSearch: true });
    if (cacheResponse) {
      return cacheResponse;
    }
    return await fetch(event.request);
  })());
```

You can break it apart to make more sense visually:

```js
/**
 * @param {FetchEvent} event
 * @return {void}
 */
function onFetch(event) {
  if (event.preloadResponse) {
    // Respond with an already created Response object
    event.respondWith(event.preloadResponse);
    return;
  }
  /** @return {Promise<Response>} */
  const fetchFromCacheWithFallback = async () => {
    const cacheResponse = await self.caches.match(event.request, { ignoreSearch: true });
    if (cacheResponse) return cacheResponse;
    return await fetch(event.request);
  };
  event.respondWith(fetchFromCacheWithFallback());
```

And of course, you can break it up even more changing it to `fetchFromCacheWithFallback(event)` and passing `event`.

Remember that `respondWith` expects an Response object or a Promise that returns an `Response`. Be careful not to make the mistake of passing a function (that when called returns a Promise that a Response). So if you have an `async` function you must execute it and return the value (which is a `Promise<Response>`).